# Capistrano on FreeBSD: GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo: Command not found

Tags: capistrano

I'm using Capistrano to deploy a PHP application to a FreeBSD server automatically. After configuration, I faced this error:

```
 [703e9962]        GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo: Command not found.
 (Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
 cap aborted!
 SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as user@example-domain.com: git exit status: 1
 git stdout: Nothing written
 git stderr: GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo: Command not found.
```

SSHKit::Command::Failed: git exit status: 1
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo: Command not found.

I replaced real account information with the "user@example-domain.com" in the above log.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Finally I decided to use rocketeer (http://rocketeer.autopergamene.eu) for my deployment. Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 0):

FreeBSD's default shell is tcsh, which will fail to execute that command. If you change it to bash, it will work:

```
sudo  chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash user
```

And make sure bash is installed.